# How can i setup repositories for atifactory for use it offline

Tags: ruby, installation, repository, artifactory, offline

I am trying to configure JFrog Artifactory to work as a local repository; that is, once I have the dependencies in its cache, I will be able to work with these same dependencies without needing to be online. I tried to do it for Ruby but it keeps telling me:

```
user@machine:~> gem install faker -V
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.localhost
HEAD http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/api/v1/dependencies?gems=faker
200 OK
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'faker' (>= 0) in any repository
GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
```

I have looked for this error in the artifactory guides where they tell me to put it in offline mode so it stops doing fetch in the remote repositories, but even so it keeps giving me errors.

If it matters I am using proxy, but it is well configured. When I am online all of my dependencies are installed just fine.

[My setup for ruby-remote repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTp66.png)

Artifactory log:

```
2018-02-12 08:11:39,550 [http-nio-8081-exec-10] [INFO ] (o.a.a.g.h.RubyHelper:150) - Initialized RubyHelper successfully
```

2018-02-12 08:11:44,666 [online-monitor-gems-remote] [INFO ] (o.a.r.HttpRepo      :1057) - gems-remote is inaccessible. Setting as offline!
2018-02-12 08:14:05,082 [online-monitor-gems-remote] [INFO ] (o.a.r.HttpRepo      :1050) - gems-remote is back online!

Here is my artifactory request log:

```
20180212080758|44|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/|HTTP/1.1|200|0
```

20180212080758|7|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|105|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_core.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|110|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_services.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|212|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/templates.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|25|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/css/vendorStyles.119.css|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|164|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_dao.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|169|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_ui.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|76|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_ui_components.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|13|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_filters.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|10|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_views.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|46|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_directives.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|70|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_states.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|92|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/favicon.119.ico|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|348|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/css/application.119.css|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|316|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/artifactory_main.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|670|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/vendorScripts.119.js|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080758|14|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.119.woff|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|15|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.119.woff|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|385|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/treebrowser/repoOrder|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|451|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|55|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|400|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/onboarding/initStatus|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|64|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|77|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|10|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|17|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080759|16|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|799|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/current|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|271|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/home/widget/artifactCount|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|31|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/artifactory_logo.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|13|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.119.woff|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|26|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.119.woff|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|51|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/fonts/artifactory.119.woff2|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|17|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/home/widget/info|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|44|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/home/widget/addon|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|23|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/userguide.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|7|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/blogs.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|27|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/support.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|39|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/stackoverflow.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|54|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/webinar.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080800|51|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/images/rest_api.119.svg|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080801|254|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/home/widget/latestBuilds|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080801|684|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/home/widget/mostDownloaded|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080801|1091|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|POST|/ui/treebrowser|HTTP/1.1|200|15
20180212080818|24|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|POST|/ui/auth/loginRelatedData|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080818|28|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/ui/oauth2/loginRequest|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080818|10|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.119.woff|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080819|14|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/webapp/css/images/checkbox.119.png|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080821|621|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|POST|/ui/auth/login|HTTP/1.1|200|53
20180212080821|6|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/home/widget/artifactCount|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080822|214|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/onboarding/initStatus|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080822|4|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080822|4|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/home/widget/info|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080822|5|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/home/widget/addon|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080822|223|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/treebrowser|HTTP/1.1|200|15
20180212080822|8|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/home/widget/latestBuilds|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080822|176|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/home/widget/mostDownloaded|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080825|14|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/webapp/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.119.woff|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080825|167|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/treebrowser|HTTP/1.1|200|15
20180212080826|44|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/webapp/css/images/checkbox_checked.119.png|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080826|32|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/webapp/images/32px.119.png|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080826|50|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/treebrowser/tabsAndActions|HTTP/1.1|200|97
20180212080826|38|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/artifactactions/download|HTTP/1.1|200|29
20180212080826|67|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/artifactgeneral|HTTP/1.1|200|62
20180212080826|10|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/auth/canAnnotate|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080827|4|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/treebrowser/tabsAndActions|HTTP/1.1|200|95
20180212080827|4|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/artifactactions/download|HTTP/1.1|200|28
20180212080827|9|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/artifactgeneral|HTTP/1.1|200|61
20180212080828|3|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/auth/canAnnotate|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080831|78|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/generalConfig|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080831|97|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/setMeUp|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080831|103|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|GET|/ui/userApiKey|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212080844|418|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/api/gems/gems/specs.4.8.gz|HTTP/1.1|200|3849020
20180212080957|160|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/treebrowser|HTTP/1.1|200|98
20180212080959|142|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|admin|POST|/ui/treebrowser|HTTP/1.1|200|102
20180212081134|2|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|HEAD|/api/gems/gems/api/v1/dependencies|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212081141|6896|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/api/gems/gems/api/v1/dependencies|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20180212081141|70|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|anonymous|GET|/api/gems/gems/latest_specs.4.8.gz|HTTP/1.1|200|1284774

Comment: What do you see in your Artifactory logs? (request and artifactory logs)

Comment: This is the log that you request. Hope you can helpme